# ¿Cómo relacionar tablas para ver pagos con estado de pendiente?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, tengo tres tablas: **alumnos**, **montos** y **pagos_pendientes**.

Con estos campos:

Alumnos:

```
id, nombres, cédula, teléfono.
```

Montos:

```
id, id_curso, concepto, monto.
```

Pagos_pendientes:

```
id_alumno, id_monto, estado.
```

La tabla `pagos_pendientes` relaciona a las otras dos. Entonces yo debo mostrar los montos que no ha pagado cada estudiante.

El sistema funciona así:

Inscribo estudiantes en cursos, destacando que un estudiante puede estar en 1 o más cursos.

Cada curso tiene una serie de pagos según el tiempo de duración: **5 meses = 5 montos**.

Luego para procesar el pago del estudiante debo ver los montos pendientes que tiene dicho estudiante para posteriormente procesar dicho monto.

Al haber procesado el pago guardo la información en una tabla llamada `pagos_hechos` y actualizo el estado del pago a `estado=1`.

Lo que quiero saber es de que manera puedo ver esos pagos pendientes que tiene cada estudiante, los montos a pagar los guardo en la tabla montos la cual contiene el `id_curso` para saber a que curso pertenecen esos montos.

Necesito una orientación de cómo debo relacionar dichas tablas para obtener la información de forma concreta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrías resolver tu problema con dos tablas:

- `alumnos`
- `pagos`

En el presente diseño la misma tabla `pagos` serviría para indicarte el estado de cuentas general de cada estudiante, para ello sólo agregarías una columna `pagado` del tipo boolean a dicha tabla. Mediante esa columna sabrías lo que cada estudiante ha pagado o no.

Pensando en un diseño más sofisticado, podrías incluso llenar previamente la tabla `pagos` con todo lo que debe pagar cada estudiante según los cursos en que esté inscrito. En dicho diseño mejor trabajado, tendrías una tabla que maneje, según los cursos, la cantidad de pagos que hay por cada curso y el monto de dicho pago. Podrías manejar también cláusulas especiales según el estudiante, como descuentos especiales por estudiante debido a conceptos como becas u otros... De ese modo, cuando el estudiante venga  a pagar, sólo estableces a `true` el pago correspondiente al curso y a la secuencia que vino a pagar.

De ese modo te evitar tener que estar manteniendo una tercera tabla que almacene los pagos pendientes. Ganas en simplicidad y evitas tener datos en tablas redundantes.

Aquí te dejo un código de ejemplo, sabiendo que usando consultas de agrupación podrías obtener resultados interesantes según las necesidades de tu aplicación.

Espero te sirva.

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/YBLLJ44823)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alumnos_20170828 (
    alumno_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    alumno_nom VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE pagos_20170828 (
    alumno_id INT, 
    curso_id INT,
    seq_pago INT,
    monto DECIMAL (10,2),
    pagado BOOLEAN  ,
    INDEX (alumno_id,curso_id,seq_pago),
    FOREIGN KEY (alumno_id) REFERENCES alumnos_20170828(alumno_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);


INSERT INTO alumnos_20170828 (alumno_nom)
    VALUES ('Pedro'),('Santiago'),('Juan')
;


INSERT INTO pagos_20170828 (alumno_id, curso_id, seq_pago, monto, pagado)
    VALUES 
        (1, 1, 1, 500, TRUE),
        (1, 1, 2, 500, TRUE),
        (1, 2, 1, 700, TRUE),
        (1, 2, 2, 700, FALSE),
        (1, 2, 3, 700, FALSE),

        (2, 1, 1, 500, TRUE),
        (2, 1, 2, 500, TRUE),
        (2, 2, 1, 700, TRUE),
        (2, 2, 2, 700, TRUE),
        (2, 2, 3, 700, TRUE),

        (3, 1, 1, 500, TRUE),
        (3, 1, 2, 500, FALSE),
        (3, 2, 1, 700, TRUE),
        (3, 2, 2, 700, FALSE),
        (3, 2, 3, 700, FALSE)
;

-- Un estado de cuentas de cada alumno

SELECT a.alumno_nom, p.curso_id, p.seq_pago, p.monto, p.pagado 
FROM pagos_20170828 p
INNER JOIN alumnos_20170828 a 
ON p.alumno_id=a.alumno_id;


-- Cuentas pagadas del alumno 1

SELECT a.alumno_nom, p.curso_id, p.seq_pago, p.monto, p.pagado 
FROM pagos_20170828 p
INNER JOIN alumnos_20170828 a 
ON p.alumno_id=a.alumno_id
WHERE a.alumno_id=1 AND p.pagado=TRUE
ORDER BY p.curso_id,p.seq_pago
;


-- Cuentas pendientes del alumno 1

SELECT a.alumno_nom, p.curso_id, p.seq_pago, p.monto, p.pagado 
FROM pagos_20170828 p
INNER JOIN alumnos_20170828 a 
ON p.alumno_id=a.alumno_id
WHERE a.alumno_id=1 AND p.pagado=FALSE
ORDER BY p.curso_id,p.seq_pago
;
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
--Una consulta sin criterios mostraría un estado de cuentas de c/alumno

    alumno_nom  curso_id    seq_pago    monto   pagado
1   Pedro       1           1           500,00  True
2   Pedro       1           2           500,00  True
3   Pedro       2           1           700,00  True
4   Pedro       2           2           700,00  False
5   Pedro       2           3           700,00  False
6   Santiago    1           1           500,00  True
7   Santiago    1           2           500,00  True
8   Santiago    2           1           700,00  True
9   Santiago    2           2           700,00  True
10  Santiago    2           3           700,00  True
11  Juan        1           1           500,00  True
12  Juan        1           2           500,00  False
13  Juan        2           1           700,00  True
14  Juan        2           2           700,00  False
15  Juan        2           3           700,00  False


-- Lo que ha pagado el alumno 1

    alumno_nom  curso_id    seq_pago    monto   pagado
1   Pedro       1           1           500,00  True
2   Pedro       1           2           500,00  True
3   Pedro       2           1           700,00  True


-- Lo que no ha pagado el alumno 1  

    alumno_nom  curso_id    seq_pago    monto   pagado
1   Pedro       2           2           700,00  False
2   Pedro       2           3           700,00  False
```

Comment: Super entendida tu respuesta Cedano, muchisimas gracias. Has clarificado mi problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para ello lo que necesitas es validar los pagos ya realizados y los estudiantes de la tabla PAGOS_PENDIENTES y unos **INNER JOINS** a las tablas relacionadas para asi obtener las columnas que desees, tu código sería el siguiente:

```
SELECT A.nombres, M.id_curso, M.concepto, M.monto   --  Columnas que desees ver.
FROM PAGOS_PENDIENTES AS P  --  Tabla de pivoteo
INNER JOIN ALUMNOS AS A --  Join a la tabla de Alumnos
    ON (A.id = P.id_alumno)
INNER JOIN MONTOS AS M  --  Join a la tabla de Montos
    ON (P.id_monto = M.id)
WHERE P.estado = "0"    --  Pagos Pendientes
```

Espero mi respuesta te ayude, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Alejo. Tengo exactamente el mismo caso, con las mismas tablas!
Lo que yo hice fue hacer una sola tabla, pagos, con una columna "estado", y al momento de inscribirse corro un código que carga todos los pagos con su fecha de vencimiento; después consulto pagos por vencimiento y puedo pedir que envíe un mail reclamando pago a todos los que estén pendientes. Por supuesto, dependemos de los data entry que carguen en el sistema cuando un pago fue realizado.