# Problema al cambiar el horario de un estudiante a otro

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos chicos, se me ha presentado un problema el cual explico ahora: Realizo inscripciones de estudiantes en cursos los cuales tienen su duración, horario, montos a pagar, y fechas de pago únicos. Hasta aquí no hay problema las inscripciones las proceso bien, ahora lo que pasa es que se presenta el caso de que un estudiante se quiera cambiar de curso porque le parece mejor el horario del otro curso, esto se da porque pueden estar disponibles dos cursos iguales pero con diferente horario o diferente duración.

Entonces resulta que al hacer ese cambio de horario debo hacer el update al id_curso en la tabla inscritos colocando el id del curso al que se va a cambiar. Hasta allí no tengo problema.

El inconveniente viene aquí: cuando actualizo el id del curso, también debo actualizar los campos de los montos a pagar y las fechas de la tabla pagos_estudiantes, estos campos debo actualizarlos con los debidos datos pertenecientes al curso que eligió el estudiante para cambiarse. El problema es que los montos van variando cada 3, porque hay aumentos y esas cosas. Lo que he intentado hasta ahora es esto:

```
function cambiar_curso($student,$curso){
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root', '' , 'academia');

$query = "UPDATE inscritos SET id_curso = '".$curso."' WHERE id_student = 
'$student'";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);

$consulta = "SELECT 
cursos_abiertos.duracion,cursos_abiertos.inicio,detalle_cuota.monto FROM 
detalle_cuota INNER JOIN cursos_abiertos 
ON detalle_cuota.id_curso=cursos_abiertos.id WHERE cursos_abiertos.id = 
'$curso'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta);
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$repetir = $fila['duracion'];
$fechas = $fila['inicio'];
$monto = $fila['monto'];
}

$aumento = 0.2;
$concepto = 0;
$aumentaCada = 3;

for($i = 0; $i < $repetir; $i++){
if(($i>0) && ($i % $aumentaCada)==0):
  $monto = $monto*(1+$aumento);
endif;

if($i>0){
    $fechas = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$primer + 1 month"));
  }
$concepto = $concepto +1;
}

 $query2 = "UPDATE pagos_estudiantes SET id_c = '".$curso."', concepto = 
 '".$concepto."', monto = '".$monto."', fecha_a_pagar = '".$fechas."' 
 WHERE id_i = '$student' AND estado = 0";
 $sql2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

 if($sql>0 && $sql2>0):
  echo 'bien';
 else:
  echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
 endif;
 }
```

Esta es la funcion en la que pretendo hacer esos cambios, como he dicho los id del curso me los cambia bien al que he elegido, pero los montos y las fechas le actualiza el mismo dato a todas las filas. Este es el resultado, adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven los campos de concepto,monto y fecha no los actualiza bien. Por que en concepto debe aumentar de 1 en uno, en monto cada 3 montos debe aumentar el 20% y en las fechas debe aumentar 1 mes cada fila. He intentado de muchas formas pero sin resultado.! Lo que necesito es que me modifique esos campos según los datos que me traiga del curso que ha elegido el estudiante para cambiarse. Por favor necesito ayudo en esto, ya con esto terminaría casi completo mi sistema. Gracias a todos. Por cierto el campo id_i es donde guardo el id del estudiante y el campo id_c tiene el id del curso.

Si es de ayuda estas son mis tablas, acepto criticas para mejorar las relaciones para poder hacer esta operación de la mejor forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjense como debe quedar mi tabla con los datos luego de hacer el update, y comparen a como queda cuando hago el cambio, comparen las dos imágenes, una es la de la inscripción normal y la otra es cuando el cambio con el update:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Donde tienes declarada la variable $primer, veo que la usas en strtotime y en la 3 consulta pero no veo de donde toma su valor

Comment: porque no tienes una tabla aparte de horarios, que relacione cursos. Asi podras asignarles horarios a los estudiantes sin modificar los cursos.

Comment: Otra es, si los cursos son iguales (precio etc), ¿con cambiar el id del curso al estudiante ya valdria no? en tu tabla de pagos, le dices que ese pago lo ha hecho para el curso Y en lugar del X y ya.

Comment: Dariel disculpa es que me he equivocado, la variable $primer ahora es $fecha ya he editado, esa variable contiene la fecha de inicio de cada curso.

Comment: En  $query2, ¿has dicho que id_i es la id de la inscripción no? porqué le pones la variable $student, que imagino que será la id del estudiante. Imagino que quieres actualizar la fila que la id del estudiante dando , ¿no?

Comment: GDP esa opción la pense, la de la tablas horarios tendria que probarlo asi, y si esa ocasión puede presentarse pero pueden haber cursos iguales pero con diferente horario, tomare en cuenta lo de la tabla horarios, esa tabla la relacionaria con la tabla cursos_abiertos no?

Comment: JuanCa eso fue error mio disculpa, alli va el id del estudiante en id_i

Comment: Que es lo mejor que me recomiendan, que cree una tabla horarios y la relacione con la tabla de cursos, y al yo aperturar un curso guardo el horario de ese curso en la tabla horarios. Al realizar la inscripción no hay problema seria lo mismo, pero al cambiar el horario lo que tendría que hacer es elegir de la tabla horarios el id del curso al que se quiere cambiar el estudiante, y de esa manera los montos y fechas del curso elegido estarían perteneciendo a ese estudiante, no se si la tabla horarios tenga que relacionarla a la tabla students?

Comment: Al actualizar la tabla pagos_estudiantes, tu tienes un id del curso en el que estaba inscrito antes ¿no? Podrías coger sólo esa fila y actualizarla

Comment: Así es JuanCa. El problema es que pueden haber muchos estudiantes inscritos en ese mismo curso, y le estaría modificando los montos a todos no? Mi función sirve para cambiar el id del curso, lo que no hace bien es actualizar tanto conceptos, montos y fechas de pago del curso que elegi para cambiar. Como han visto mis montos aumentan cada 3 y mis fechas cada 1. Y en la imagen muestro la forma en que me actualiza, la cual es nada bien.

Comment: En sintesis lo que debo es que al cambiar el id del curso a otro se me modifiquen los campos concepto, monto, y fecha a pagar con los datos del curso que he elegido. Lo que pasa es que si los montos fueran todos igual sin aumento ni nada fuera mas sencillo, pero alli se me presenta el problema.

Comment: Lo mismo no te he entendido bien, pero según estoy mirando, si tu tienes la id del curso que estaba inscrito, la id del curso del que se va a inscribir y la id del estudiante, puedes hacer hacer una consulta previa para sacar la id del cuso que estaba inscrito y luego hacer el UPDATE: UPDATE pagos_estudiantes SET id_c = '".$curso."', concepto = 
 '".$concepto."', monto = '".$monto."', fecha_a_pagar = '".$fechas."' 
 WHERE id_i = '$student' AND estado = 0 AND id_c = '$id_cursoAnterior'" o algo así, no me he fijado demasiado en las tablas

Comment: Con eso sólo actualizarás la fila del estudiante que ha cambiado de curso

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65187/discussion-between-alejo-mendoza-and-juanca).

Comment: En una [anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/97804/29967), no sé si recuerdas, había previsto este problema. Te decía esto en mi respuesta: _... En dicho diseño mejor trabajado, tendrías una tabla que maneje, según los cursos, la cantidad de pagos que hay por cada curso y el monto de dicho pago. Podrías manejar también cláusulas especiales según el estudiante, como descuentos especiales por estudiante debido a conceptos como becas u otros..._ O sea, **ligar cada monto a pagar al `id_curso` en la tabla `cursos` y cuando éste se cambie ya no tienes que actualizar nada más**.

Comment: En efecto Cedano, eso es lo que he hecho! Gracias!

Comment: ¿Entonces lo has resuelto?

Comment: Si puedes, intenta poner la solución de tu pregunta en una respuesta para que todo el mundo puede verla

Answer (score 0):

Con este codigo vas a poder incrementar las fechas.

```
<?php

 $repetir = 12; 
 $concepto =0;
 for($i = 0;  $i <  $repetir;  $i++){
    $primer = '2017-09-01';     
    if($i> 0){       
        $fechas = date('d-m-Y', 
                   strtotime("$primer +$i month"));
        echo $fechas . '<br>';
    }    
    $concepto++;
    echo $concepto . '<br>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$aum = "SELECT porcentaje FROM aumento";
$a = $mysqli->query($aum);
$row = $a->fetch_assoc();

$aumento = $row['porcentaje'];
$aumentaCada = 3;
$concepto = 0;
$estado = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $repetir; $i++){
if(($i>0) && ($i % $aumentaCada)==0):
  $monto = $monto*(1+$aumento);
endif;

if($i>0)
{
  $inicio = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$inicio + 1 month"));
}

$concepto = $concepto +1;
$query2 = "INSERT INTO pagos_estudiantes 
(id_inscripcion,concepto,monto,fecha_a_pagar,estado) VALUES 
('$val2','$concepto','$monto','$inicio','$estado')";
$sql2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
}
```

Saludos muchachos, esta ha sido la forma en que he solucionado, ahora ven esa consulta al porcentaje, porque me han pedido que tenga la capacidad el sistema de modificar el aumento de los montos cada 3 mensualidades. Gracias por su ayuda! Saludos